# Birthdate + Number of days = date

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time writing a python program that takes the inputs of a date of birth (mm-dd-yyyy) and a number of days (ex: 5000) and printing out the date the person with the date of birth will reach that number of days. For example, if I enter "05-12-1960" and "30000", I should get 07-01-2042.
So far, I have been able to get the input functions for date of birth and the number of days:

```
birthdate = input("Enter your date of birth (mm-dd-yyyy): ")
    days = input("Enter a number of days: ")
```

I'm recently new to python, so I'm still trying to learn other functions such as str, input, int, etc. Do I start with a counter or if/else statements? I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: datetime is the library you want in this case - doing it manually will be painful as you need to account for leap years, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the datetime module to convert a date string into a date object, then use `timedelta` to increment it by some number of days.

Error handling is important here too. If you are doing these operations with user input strings, adding some validation that the user actually entered a valid date and integer is important too or the program will crash if they enter an invalid entry.

Here is an example:

```py
import datetime

def get_birthday():
    """Get the birthday, catch if it is not a valid date and ask again"""
    while True:
        birthdate = input("Enter your date of birth (mm-dd-yyyy): ")
        try:
            return datetime.datetime.strptime(birthdate, "%m-%d-%Y")
        except ValueError:
            print(f"'{birthdate}' is not a valid date, try again")

def get_num_days():
    """Get the number of days, catch if it is not a valid integer and ask again"""
    while True:
        days = input("Enter a number of days: ")
        try:
            return int(days)
        except ValueError:
            print(f"'{days}' is not an integer, try again")
                
date = get_birthday()
num_days = get_num_days()

date += datetime.timedelta(days = num_days)
new_date_str = date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y")
print(f"The new date is {new_date_str}")
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. When I run the program "python3 dates.py" (dates is the name of the file), I get an NameError: 'dateofbirth' is not defined. specifically, the line is date = dateofbirth() (I replaced get_birthday with dateofbirth).

Comment: If you change the name of the function you are calling you need to change the name of the function definition too (`def get_birthday():`). Run it without changing anything first, it works.

Comment: Ok that seemed to work then, thank you

Comment: Now I'm getting an AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Comment: Did you run it exactly as provided or change something? It sounds like you added another "datetime"

Comment: Ran it exactly as is. It is pointing at the line "return datetime.datetime.striptime(birthdate, "%m-%d-%Y").

Comment: What is your import datetime line?

Comment: import datetime is my 5th line. I have four lines above it commented out describing the program.

Comment: I meant what is the text of that line... It sounds like you made a typo somewhere, the code above works. The error message you reported sounds like you are calling `datetime.datetime.datetime` - three datetimes. Copy and paste the code *exactly* to a new file with nothing else and try it there

Comment: Also, did you use `strptime` or `striptime` like you posted above? There is no "i"

Comment: Found the error in my original program, needed to use 'strptime'. Ran your program exactly as is, it worked. On the original, a new error shows up saying 'TypeError unsupported type for timedelta days component: function' I have it typed out exactly as your code.

Comment: You probably tried to set `days=the_name_of_a_function` instead of `days=some_variable` in `timedelta`. You need to learn to debug things yourself, start with the working version and change one thing at a time. If it breaks, you know the thing you changed broke it

Comment: Ran the debugger and finally figure it out, it has to match the variable set above (num_days). Sorry for being a pest, I do appreciate your time and patience

Comment: Good work - the debugger is definitely a useful tool to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime` to parse the datetimes.

```py
import datetime

birthdate = input("Enter your date of birth (mm-dd-yyyy): ")
days = input("Enter a number of days: ")

birthdate = ''.join([birthdate[i] for i in (6, 7, 8, 9, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)])  # reorder the string to convert `mm-dd-yyyy` to `yyyy-mm-dd`
birthtime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(birthdate).timestamp()  # get timestamp in seconds
time_after = birthtime + int(days)*86400
new = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time_after)

# do things
print(f'It will be {new.year}, month {new.month} day {new.day}')
```

---

Output:

```
Enter your date of birth (mm-dd-yyyy): 01-01-2022
Enter a number of days: 14
It will be 2022, month 1 day 15
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. My instructor informed that the output for this program needs to be in the mm-dd-yyyy format.

Comment: You can change the print format and do something like `print('{new.month}-{new.day}-{new.year}')` and get `1-15-2022`.

Comment: Thank you for this, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@cscale-82-69 python]# cat dateime.py 
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
  
startdate = datetime.strptime("2022-5-1", "%Y-%m-%d")
print(startdate)
finaldate = startdate + timedelta(days=5000)
print(finaldate)
```

Sample output

```
[root@cscale-82-69 python]# python dateime.py
2022-05-01 00:00:00
2036-01-08 00:00:00
[root@cscale-82-69 python]#
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help. My instructor informed me that the output needs to be in the mm-dd-yyyy format and it looks like the output is in yyyy-mm-dd.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you should start learning the modules available in the Python Standard Library. For your task you may use the `datetime` module.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Your input functions
birthdate = input("Enter your date of birth (mm-dd-yyyy): ")
days = input("Enter a number of days: ")

# Using the calendar functions from datetime module
dateformat = '%m-%d-%Y'
# redefining a name is usually not a good practice
birthdate = datetime.strptime(birthdate, dateformat) 
newdate = birthdate + timedelta(days = int(days))
print(newdate.strftime(dateformat))
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I will start looking at the standard library